# php form mail (post) still not working

Tags: php

I am trying to complete a simple form send but although it now appears to send the email - nothing is sent..

```
$name = $_POST['name']; //Sender's name
$email = $_POST['email']; //Sender's email
$message_text = $_POST['message']; //Sender's message
$phone = $_POST['phone']; //Sender's phone no
$methodOfContact = $_POST['methodOfContact']; //Sender's methodOfContact
$group1 = $_POST['group1']; //Sender's an existing customer
$other = $_POST['other']; //filler
$AppointmentType = $_POST['AppointmentType']; //Sender's AppointmentType
$WhenSuits = $_POST['WhenSuits']; //Sender's WhenSuits
$message = $_POST['message']; //Sender's message


//Declare which field naems we're already using.
$currently_active = array(  'name',
                            'email',
                            'message',
                            'phone',
                            'methodOfContact',
                            'group1',
                            'AppointmentType',
                            'WhenSuits'
                            );


//Add fields added through theme options page to Email
$custom = '';
foreach ($currently_active as $key => $currently_active) {

    if($currently_active['value']) {

        $custom.= $currently_active['name'] . ": " . $currently_active['value'] ."<br /> \n";

    }

}
```

THANK YOU EVERYBODY FOR ANY HELP - I AM REALLY GRATEFUL!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: There is no values assigned into the variable $user_fields? and the variable `$custom.=` should be `$custom .=`

Comment: Thanks all - sorry to be a pain but what would be the best way to initialize the "$user_fields" variable so that it takes each of the form fields...  should I just : $user_fields = array(  'name',
                            'email',
                            'message',
                            'phone',
                            'methodOfContact',
                            'group1',
                            'AppointmentType',
                            'WhenSuits'
                            );

Answer (score 2):

`$user_fields` is not an array so when you use it with a foreach with key => values pairs it won't work.